# How to remove shipping details from cart and email

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, magento2.4, shipping-address

I want to hide shipping method from cart and emails.

1. /checkout/cart/
2. /checkout/#payment
   [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please override your file

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js
```

to

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js
```

Change Below Function Your Theme

```
getShippingMethodTitle: function () {
        var shippingMethod,
            shippingMethodTitle = '';

        if (!this.isCalculated()) {
            return '';
        }
        shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();

        if (typeof shippingMethod['method_title'] !== 'undefined') {
            shippingMethodTitle = shippingMethod['method_title'];
        }

        return shippingMethod ? shippingMethodTitle : '';
    },
```

Comment: Hi Ramesh, I've not found this kind of method in shipping.js